# Import error when loading my shared library at python code.

Tags: python, c++, boost, makefile, pyenv

I would like to ask a question about building a following code. A problem is I can not call complied .so file from python object. Maybe, a reason is python can not find one of boost libraries(libboost_python.dylib). But $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH have a directory that libboost_python.dylib was installed.

```
//klass.cxx
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class World
{
public:
  void set(std::string msg) { this->msg = msg; }
  std::string greet() { return msg; }
  std::string msg;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE( klass )
{
  using namespace boost::python;

  class_<World>("World")
    .def("greet",&World::greet)
    .def("set",&World::set)
    ;
}
```

I assume I will access this c++ class and its mender functions from python code. For example,

```
# klass.py
import klass
a = klass.World()
```

And makefile to build this code is

```
#makefile
CONDADIR=/Users/XYZ/.anyenv/envs/pyenv/versions/anaconda2-4.0.0
INCDIR=$(CONDADIR)/include
PYDIR=$(INCDIR)/python2.7
OPT=-I$(INCDIR) -I$(PYDIR) -L$(CONDADIR)/lib  -lpython2.7 -lboost_python
#RPATHOPT=-rpath -Xlinker $(CONDADIR)/lib

all:klass.cxx
        g++ $(RPATHOPT) -fPIC -shared $(OPT) -o klass.so klass.cxx
```

After building this code make command produced "klass.so" on my working directory. Now run python code which call c++ class "World".

```
[XYZ@OSX wrapper_boost] python klass.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "klass.py", line 2, in <module>
    import klass
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/XYZ/Work/python/wrapper_boost/klass.so,
2):Library not loaded: @rpath/./libboost_python.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/XYZ/Work/python/wrapper_boost/klass.so
  Reason: image not found
```

DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is ...

```
[XYZ@OSX wrapper_boost] echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH    
 :/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1:/usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2d_1/lib:/Users/XYZ/.anyenv/envs/pyenv/versions/anaconda2-4.0.0/lib
```

The libraries which ware linked with produced .so file are

```
[XYZ@OSX wrapper_boost] otool -L klass.so 
klass.so:
    klass.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    libpython2.7.dylib (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0)
    @rpath/./libboost_python.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 120.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

Any advices?

Best, Hashi

Comment: Have you tried to google `"Library not loaded: @rpath"`?